# View-based TableView: Initializing column of popups to same values and interacting with them (Xcode Storyboard)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have a setup as in the following:
[image]

I would like to set the values of every Popup Button (nested in a Table Cell View) to the same range of values, as well as interact with them in other ways. In short, I require an IBOutlet.

ideal initialization code:

```
let tableArray = [outlet1, outlet2, outlet3, outlet4, ...]
for i in 0...tableArray.count-1 {
    for v in 1...127 {
        tableArray[i].addItem(v)
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt to add all their outlets into the View Controller class (MIDI Channel Settings), I get the error *the outlets are invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.*

The following: [Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561461/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content-ios), [Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014235/outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content), [Swift - Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550519/swift-outlets-cannot-be-connected-to-repeating-content?rq=1) (in addition to being based on UIKit not AppKit) all suggest the same solution: create a unique subclass for each cell and initialize the outlet for each cell to that subclass.

1. It is pretty onerous to have 16 different subclasses just for the cells in one column.
2. There is no way to assemble them into an array for the purpose of doing what I did in the code above.

How would I be able to interact with this column of popup buttons I created?

Comment: Why do you have so many cells? How do you want to interact with the popup buttons?

Comment: What's the point of using NSTableCellView if you don't reuse the same cell?

Answer (score -1):

From what I gather this is only possible programmatically or through Cocoa bindings.
While it may sound complicated, a good and simple overview of creating TableViews programmatically is to be found here: https://www.appcoda.com/macos-programming-tableview/

It also explains what all those answers meant by 'subclassing the tableviewcell'.